# Why this integral converges to the beta distribution?

Tags: density-function, beta-distribution, integral

[image]

I know the beta distribution has a domain of [0,1] and I know the pdf but I just don't understand how the second last step here led to the last step.

Comment: I don't see anything converging to anything else.  There's nothing going on here except direct application of the definitions of the Beta function and the incomplete Beta integral.

Comment: I agree -- this is nothing mode than definitions that you seem to say you already know.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The trick to the last integral: the integrand is an un-normalized Beta PDF, so the result must equal the normalizing constant of the corresponding Beta PDF.

$\int_0^1 \frac{1}{B(c, d)}\theta^{c-1}(1-\theta)^{d-1}=1 \implies \int_0^1 \theta^{c-1}(1-\theta)^{d-1}=B(c, d)$